# ddsmoothmenu expand all menu item at first time open

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use knockout to bindding item to my menu, I used `ddsmoothmenu`. But proplem when the page load, the menu expandse all the item inside, I want it collapse all ultil user hover.
Please see my attachment image.

[**Link Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jbym4/)

My html:

```
<div id="smoothmenu1" class="ddsmoothmenu-v">
    <ul class="item-container" data-bind="foreach: tools">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <span class="box-item-name" data-bind="text: name"></span>
                <i class="icon" data-bind="attr: {style: 'background: url(images/' + icon + ') no-repeat'}"></i>
            </a>
            <ul class="tool-item-wrapper" data-bind="foreach: $data.items">
                <li class="tool-item " data-bind="css: {'has-child':  $data.items && !!$data.items.length}">
                    <a href="javascript:;" data-bind="text: name"> </a>
                    <!-- ko if: $data.items && !!$data.items.length -->
                    <ul data-bind="foreach: items">
                        <li class="item-name"><a href="javascript:;" data-bind="text: name"> </a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My config:

```
// toolbox
    ddsmoothmenu.init({
        mainmenuid: "smoothmenu1", //Menu DIV id
        orientation: 'h', //Horizontal or vertical menu: Set to "h" or "v"
        classname: 'ddsmoothmenu_2', //class added to menu's outer DIV
        method: 'hover', // set to 'hover' (default) or 'toggle'
        // arrowswap: true, // enable rollover effect on menu arrow images?
        //customtheme: ["#804000", "#482400"],
        contentsource: "markup" //"markup" or ["container_id", "path_to_menu_file"]
    });
```

I try this tip but no luck:

```
 setTimeout(function () {
        $("#smoothmenu1").find("ul").hover();
    }, 1000);
```

Page load:

[image]

After I hover to menu:

[image]

Please help me fix it with simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason, the event to collapse all menu should be `mouseleave()`, not `hover()`.

Working code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#smoothmenu1").find("ul").mouseleave();
}, 1000);
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jbym4/9/)

When I digged into `jquery`, the implement of `hover()` is:

```
hover: function( fnOver, fnOut ) {
        return this.mouseenter( fnOver ).mouseleave( fnOut || fnOver );
    },
```

Maybe when the `mouseenter` event trigger, the `ddsmoothmenu` do something and it doesnot finish before the `mouseleave` event trigger.